# prevent duplicate record being enter in DataGridView

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, visual-c++, event-handling

Process is as follow

Entering record from textboxs to datagridview and then to database

when enter data into textbox and fire the click event of **Enter the data into datagridview button**

constraint check is that ID being enter. Is already exist or not..? the code for that is

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If txt_id.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("id").Value.ToString Then
            MessageBox.Show("record already exist")
        End If
    Next
```

**butt it throw an exception**  NullReferenceException

**why** when at first time it checks there is no record in **row(i).cells("id")**

How tackle this problem.....?

Comment: DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows =  false

Is there any other mechanism

Comment: Did you try to read the data in the `RowsAdded` event as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded.aspx

Comment: this event Occurs after a new row is added to the DataGridView But we check Constraints between when data flowing from textboxs to (here checking constraint) datagridview because we check all other constrain there so we are bound there.

Comment: you can try the `RowValidating` event then. The list of events that can be consulted is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4dwfh7x.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
If Datagridview1.rows.count > 0 then
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If txt_id.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("id").Value.ToString Then
            MessageBox.Show("record already exist")
        End If
    Next
End if
```

Comment: its also thrown exception nullreferenceexception the only solution i find is DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false

Comment: Because your question is .. **why when at first time it checks there is no record** .. and you have checking routine ..

Comment: i mean i check constraint before data going to datagridview